# Failed to authenticate on Gmail SMTP server

Tags: symfony, email, gmail

I'm trying to send emails via gmail in a Symfony 5 online application.
Here is my configuration (`swiftmailer.yaml`) :

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    auth_mode: login
    port: 465
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    username: my_username
    password: '%env(MAILER_GMAIL_PASSWORD)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

And here is the error that I've got :

app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "my_username" using 1 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "534", with message "534-5.7.14  534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14  Learn more at 534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 a10sm1287053wrm.87 - gsmtp ". [] []

I followed the steps on the link in the error (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754), and nothing has changed.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue deleting this line in configuration of swiftmailer:

`auth_mode: login`